# Regex first match on or operation

Tags: regex, perl

Assume we have the following string:

```
$text = "colors: red-FF0000,green-00FF00,blue-0000FF";
```

If I want to check the Hex value if the string contains `red` I would use the following statement:

```
($color,$hex) = $text =~ /colors\:\s+.*(red)-(.*?),.*/
```

I would get the values `red` and `00FF00` for each respective variable. All is well at this point.

Now, say I want to check if the string contains either `red` or `green` but get only the **first** occurring color. I tried

```
($color,$hex) = $text =~ /colors\:\s+.*(red|green)-(.*?),.*/
```

but I would get `green` for `$color` instead of `red`. Is there a way to fix the RegEx to get the first matching color in the pipe list? I tried using `(red|green)?` but it seems this is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` before the `(red|green)` is the problem. It does a greedy matching, eating your `red` portion and then finding a match at `green`. You need to make it non-greedy by placing a `?` after it.

```
($color,$hex) = $text =~ /colors\:\s+.*?(red|green)-(.*?),.*/
```

This would work.

Comment: This. Worked for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.*` after whitespace match `\s+`:

```
my ($color,$hex) = $text =~ /colors\:\s+(red|green)-(.*?),.*/;
```

Here is code:

```
my $text = "colors: red-FF0000,green-00FF00,blue-0000FF";

my ($color,$hex) = $text =~ /colors\:\s+(red|green)-(.*?),.*/;

print "$color : $hex\n";
```

Output:

```
red : FF0000
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I still get `green` for `$color`.

Comment: What if I have another color before red? For example, `"colors: yellow-00FFFF,red-FF0000,green-00FF00,blue-0000FF"`.

Comment: @MrvS: Then change this `(red|green)` with `(red|green|yellow)` and you will get first color i.e. yellow. You should test it from yourself.

Comment: @serenesat: Your regex expects one of the colors from the `(red|green|yellow)` to be immediately present after the \s+. if you are searching for `(blue|green)` in the above string, it won't work.

Comment: @Thaha: Did you not read this line '_to get the first matching color in the pipe list_' in question? OP wants to match first color and for that above code is working fine.

Comment: Seems my question was not clear. As I have said, there can still be other text before red, etc. It can be a color or not which I do not need.